# Playwright - How to get page.on('response') promisse body content

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

```
page.on('response', async response => {
        if (response.url().endsWith("verifica_autenticidade?ck=0")){
            console.log('body===> '+ await response.body());
            
        }
    });
```

It prints  [object Promise].

How to get the response body? I need to get the body of the requested page.

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: you are stringifying the promise by concating. Meaning it will just show the object type, in this case `object promise` remove the string in your `console.log` and maybe even set a var to the response instead then console log it.

Comment: thanks. Will give it a try

Comment: You were right guys... i just saved it in a new variable then the 'promisse' thing was gone!